# Why the method closest() doesn't find the closest class in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating dynamically next classes with input field, however when I want to remove previous row - I get nothing.. What can be the problem?

my javascript code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        var newCommercial = $("<div class='singleCommercial'><div class='form-group'><input class='datetimepicker'></div>");
        newCommercial.appendTo($('#listOfCommercials'));

        newCommercial.find('.datetimepicker').val(dd+"/"+mm+"/"+yy+" "+time).datetimepicker();
    });

    $("#delete_row").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.singleCommercial').remove();

    });
});
```

and the full page can be visible in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7yd5o63q/12/

Thanks!

Comment: Please describe how you understand the meaning of `closest` method. I have a feeling that you don't know what `closest` actually does.

Comment: You need to quote the HTML (**in** the question, not just linked).

Comment: closest()  returns the first ancestor, [info](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` is used to select the closest **ancestor**. The element you're interested in is not the ancestor of the button.

In your case, you want to remove the *last* element, you can use the `:last` selector or you can also use `last()`.

You also have duplicate id `singleCommercial` in your markup. This is not valid HMTL, you can remove this. If you want you can use it as class.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7yd5o63q/15/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    var newCommercial = $("<div class='singleCommercial'><div class='form-group'><input class='datetimepicker'></div>");
    newCommercial.appendTo($('#listOfCommercials'));

    // newCommercial.find('.datetimepicker').val(dd + "/" + mm + "/" + yy + " " + time).datetimepicker();
  });

  $("#delete_row").click(function() {
    $('.singleCommercial:last').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="listOfCommercials">
  <div id="singleCommercial">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type='text' class="form-control datetimepicker" id='datetimepicker' name="appearanceDate0" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default">Add Row</button>
<button id="delete_row" class="btn btn-default">Delete Row</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to remove the last `.singleCommercial` element from the list where you are appending div.

You should try

```
$("#delete_row").click(function() {
    $('#listOfCommercials > .singleCommercial').last().remove();
});
```

The `.closest()` function in jQuery selects the element which is parent ancestor to the current element. Since the element `#delete_row` referred by your `this` variable is unable to locate the `.singleCommercial` using the `.closest()` fn since it is not its parent and is in a different hierarchy so it returns an empty set of jQuery objects and nothing is getting removed.

How to achieve this is  you can either delete the last element in the `#listOfCommercials` block. Or you can add a delete button inside the `.singleCommercial` and then use `.closest()` so that it will remove the whole block.

Updated Demo Fiddle for removing only the last element in the `#listOfCommercials` div block

http://jsfiddle.net/zmL7j3xL/1/